# How to convert data from column to rows And rows to column using oracle sql

Tags: pivot, unpivot

[image: Sample Data view]

how to do this using unpivot & pivot?
Or is there any other option available in oracle?

tried something like this

SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
*
FROM
pivot_test UNPIVOT ( val
FOR col
IN ( col_1,
col_2,
col_1_percentage,
col_2_percentage ) )
) PIVOT (
SUM ( val )
FOR ( yr )
IN ( 2021,
2022 )
);
I am sure it is not correct ..

Comment: This may help you https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp as(
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            pivot_test UNPIVOT ( val
                FOR col
            IN ( col_1,
                 col_2,
                 col_1_per,
                 col_2_per ) )
    ) PIVOT (
        SUM ( val )
        FOR ( yr )
        IN ( 2021,
        2022 )
    )
    )
    select t1.*, t2."2021" as "2021%", t2."2022" as "2022%" from 
    temp t1
    inner join temp t2
    on t2.col=concat(t1.col,'_per')
  where NOT t1.col NOT like '%_per'
```

But I think we can do it in a better way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).